# Creating "ordinal" clusters based on List Integer elements in Java based on unique set

Tags: java, arraylist, grouping, clustered-index

I am trying to create ordered clusters starting from 1 using numbers in a List Integer.

For example, if I have a List Integer like: [-1, 7, 99, 4, 5, 33, 6, 4,  77, 3, 7, 99, 2, 7], these numbers are clusters returned by an algorithm. The algorithm won't create consecutive numbering like 1, 2, 3... but rather would "jump" randomly.

So what I want to achieve is more or less, a cleaned version of the clusters. The only exception is that any number in the above list that is -1, will remain -1 in the new List of ordered numbered clusters.

To illustrate this, suppose the above list, I create a set of unique elements: {-1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 33, 77, 99} for these unique clusters, I would like to create new numbering, for instance changing the set to say {-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} to replace the previous set while keeping -1 intact. Each index in previous set corresponds to index in the new set.

Having that new set, I want to then run through the List Integer and update it accordingly. So, for the example above I would have: [-1, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 8, 2, 6, 9, 1, 6].

**What I have done so far?**

```
import java.util.*;

public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] myIntArray = new int[]{-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, -1, 7, 5, 9, 5, 5, 10,
            4, 14, -1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 14, 5, 22, 5, 5, 25, 5, 22, 22, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 5, 5, 14, 14, 5,
            5, 22, 9, 2, 5, 22, -1, 47, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, -1, -1, 5, 5, 22, 5, 5, 5, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 65, 5,
            5, 5, 5, 14, 5, 10, 5, -1, 5, 22, 5, 14, 14, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 22, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, -1, -1, 90, 22,
            -1, 92, 47, -1, 65, -1, 47, -1, 5, 1, -1, 7, 47, 92, -1, 9, -1, 9, -1, 103, 47, 3, 14, 107, 1,
            92, -1, 4, -1, 4, 14, -1, 9, -1, -1, 22, -1, 9, 22, 92, 25, 92, 9, 14, -1, 92, 103, 47, 4, -1,
            22, 9, 92, 47, -1, 47, 9, 7, 107, -1, -1, 47, 9, 14, 4, 47, -1, 22, 4, 22, 9, 9, 90, -1, -1, 4,
            4, 22, 22, 103, 47, 47, -1, -1, 9, 14, 9, 4, 4, 22, 22, 159, 9, 103, 4, 22, 4, 159, 90, 4};

    List<Integer> myListInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>(myIntArray.length);

    // passing values to myListInteger from myIntArray
    for (int i : myIntArray) {
        myListInteger.add(i);
    }

    // get distinct numbers in myListInteger: Set
    Set<Integer> distinctNumbersSet = new HashSet<Integer>(myListInteger);

    // convert to List
    List<Integer> distinctIntegerList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer i: distinctNumbersSet) {
        distinctIntegerList.add(i);
    }

    // index to start numbering unique values
    int index = 1;
    boolean increaseIndex = false;


    for (int i = 0; i < distinctIntegerList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myListInteger.size(); j++ ) {
            if (myListInteger.get(j) == -1) {
                continue;
            }

            if (distinctIntegerList.get(i) == myListInteger.get(j)) {
                myListInteger.set(j, index);
                increaseIndex = true;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (increaseIndex == true) {
            index++;
            increaseIndex = false;
        }

    }

    // after update the myListInteger, I can get distinct sets again
    Set<Integer> distinctSetAfterUpdate = new HashSet<Integer>(myListInteger);

    System.out.println(myListInteger); // there is a 159 almost at the end, while it is expected that it should be 18

    for (Integer ind: distinctSetAfterUpdate) {
        System.out.println(ind + ": " +  Collections.frequency(myListInteger, ind));
    }



    }
}
```

**Problem I get**

The highest cluster in the list: 159 which appears twice, is not going to new cluster 18... If I try to visualize the distribution on the new mapping, somehow this 159 appears as cluster with 1 value and 18 appears with 1 too..., while based on my logic in the code this new cluster mapping **should never go past the size of the the set.**

So my current output for visualizing the distribution is:

```
-1: 33
1: 3
2: 2
3: 2
4: 17
5: 56
6: 4
7: 16
8: 2
9: 12
10: 19
11: 2
12: 12
13: 2
14: 3
15: 7
16: 4
17: 2
18: 1
159: 1
```

while I want to get

```
-1: 33
1: 3
2: 2
3: 2
4: 17
5: 56
6: 4
7: 16
8: 2
9: 12
10: 19
11: 2
12: 12
13: 2
14: 3
15: 7
16: 4
17: 2
18: 2
```

Any help trying to understand why my code does not map the 159 twice into 18 but only once?

Comment: Okay, here's my problem with this. I don't understand what you're actually trying to accomplish. Getting an ordered list of unique values is straightforward, but after that, it doesn't really make sense. Maybe you understand it better than I do from your description, but if you can't explain the problem clearly, then trying to code it is going to be as big a mess.

Comment: What happen is that the List of values I have above represent "clusters" in my problem. But since the initial code that generate them is not really of importance, the issue is, I would like those "clusters" to be "smooth", if you want to present the problem to someone and tell there is cluster 45, 90, etc, then they can ask, where are intermediate clusters? Since there isn't then I create unique set of numbers, and want to replace this set into ordered numbers starting from 1, while ignoring number -1 in the list i.e. leaving them as it is in the new list. The -1 has a meaning: unclustered.

Comment: The steps you take to get from `{-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` => ` [-1, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 8, 2, 6, 9, 1, 6]` are not clear

Comment: Also, the output I pasted above, is just to visualize the distribution on the new list, thus from it I can see that there is a problem, 159 which was element from the original list is not supposed to be there. I have no clue how to remove it, since based on my code, it is supposed to land in the "cluster" 18, thus 18 having 2 elements.

Comment: @Eritrean, what I showed in the example is basically that I want to replace the numbers in the set to ordered numbers starting from 1 except for number -1 i.e. I leave it as it is....  Then after doing that, I then go back to the list from which the set is based, and replace the numbers with the new numbers from the new set...

Comment: And what are the replacement rules? I don't see no interrelations except for the `-1` .

Comment: the replacement rule is that, I start navigating through the set of (old) clusters, if there is -1 then there is no replacement in the list of cluster values, else for the first element in the set that is not -1, that element is cluster 1 in the List, wherever it appears... and the same repeats for subsequent elements in the set.

Comment: @Eritrean, I updated the description to make it more clear... basically my logic fails on the highest number in the list, making it not to map correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
if (distinctIntegerList.get(i) == myListInteger.get(j))
```

You have Integer types in your lists. The `==` is used to compare primitive types (int, long, double ..).
You should always use equals method when comparing reference types (Integer, Double, Long)

Change that line to

```
if (distinctIntegerList.get(i).equals(myListInteger.get(j)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't know this. I am new to Java :-)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use maps for your task instead of lists, which makes the code a bit readable:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MainData {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myIntArray = new int[]{-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, -1, 7, 5, 9, 5, 5, 10,
            4, 14, -1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 14, 5, 22, 5, 5, 25, 5, 22, 22, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 5, 5, 14, 14, 5,
            5, 22, 9, 2, 5, 22, -1, 47, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, -1, -1, 5, 5, 22, 5, 5, 5, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 65, 5,
            5, 5, 5, 14, 5, 10, 5, -1, 5, 22, 5, 14, 14, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 22, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, -1, -1, 90, 22,
            -1, 92, 47, -1, 65, -1, 47, -1, 5, 1, -1, 7, 47, 92, -1, 9, -1, 9, -1, 103, 47, 3, 14, 107, 1,
            92, -1, 4, -1, 4, 14, -1, 9, -1, -1, 22, -1, 9, 22, 92, 25, 92, 9, 14, -1, 92, 103, 47, 4, -1,
            22, 9, 92, 47, -1, 47, 9, 7, 107, -1, -1, 47, 9, 14, 4, 47, -1, 22, 4, 22, 9, 9, 90, -1, -1, 4,
            4, 22, 22, 103, 47, 47, -1, -1, 9, 14, 9, 4, 4, 22, 22, 159, 9, 103, 4, 22, 4, 159, 90, 4};
        //distinct values of your array collected to list
        List<Integer> myListInteger = Arrays.stream(myIntArray).boxed().distinct().sorted()
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(myListInteger);

        //map your unique values to there index, except -1
        Map<Integer, Integer> indexToUniqueValue = new HashMap<>();
        indexToUniqueValue.put(-1, -1);

        for (int i = 1; i < myListInteger.size(); i++) {
            indexToUniqueValue.put(i, myListInteger.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println(indexToUniqueValue);

        //map the indexes to frequency in your original array
        Map<Integer, Integer> indexToFrequency = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : indexToUniqueValue.entrySet()) {
            indexToFrequency.put(entry.getKey(), countFreq(entry.getValue(), myIntArray));
        }
        System.out.println(indexToFrequency);
    }

    private static Integer countFreq(Integer value, int[] myIntArray) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i : myIntArray) {
            if (i == value) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one too, pretty neat :-)